# Cocos2dx Web services Json

Tags: json, cocos2d-x

I am new in cocos2dx .. I have some doubts in json parsing . I have got messages from server .But I cant post messages to the server . here i paste the code of getmessages. Plz hel me to post messages.Thanks in Advance.

```
void ChatRoom::function()
{

std::vector<std::string> headers;
headers.push_back("Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8");
cocos2d::extension::CCHttpRequest * request = new cocos2d::extension::CCHttpRequest();
request->setUrl("url here");

const char* postData ="chatManagerRequestType=GET_MESSAGES_AFTER_CHAT_ENABLED";


request->setRequestType(cocos2d::extension::CCHttpRequest::kHttpGet);
request->setResponseCallback(this, httpresponse_selector(ChatRoom::onHttpRequestCompleted));
request->setRequestData(postData, strlen(postData));
request->setHeaders(headers);
cocos2d::extension::CCHttpClient::getInstance()->send(request);
request->release();
}

void ChatRoom::onHttpRequestCompleted(cocos2d::CCNode *sender, void *data)
{

cocos2d::extension::CCHttpResponse * response = (cocos2d::extension::CCHttpResponse *)data;

if (!response)
{
    return;
}  std::string command;
if (0 != strlen(response->getHttpRequest()->getTag()))
{
    command = response->getHttpRequest()->getTag();
    CCLog("%s completed", response->getHttpRequest()->getTag());
}

int statusCode = response->getResponseCode();
char statusString[64] = {};
sprintf(statusString, "HTTP Status Code: %d, tag = %s", statusCode, response->getHttpRequest()->getTag());
CCLog("response code: %d", statusCode);

if (!response->isSucceed())
{
    CCLog("response failed");
    CCLog("error buffer: %s", response->getErrorBuffer());
    return;
}

std::vector<char> * buffer = response->getResponseData();

char * concatenated = (char *) malloc(buffer->size() + 1);
std::string s2(buffer->begin(), buffer->end());
strcpy(concatenated, s2.c_str());
CCLOG("%s",s2.c_str());
CCArray *arry=new CCArray();



printf("Http Test, dump data: ");
std::string tstr;
for (unsigned int i = 0; i < buffer->size(); i++)
{
    char s[10];
    sprintf(s, "%c",(*buffer)[i]);
    tstr += (*buffer)[i];
    arry->addObject((CCObject*)s);

}

for (int i=0; i<9; i++) {
    cocos2d::extension::Json * jsondd = cocos2d::extension::Json_create(concatenated);


    cocos2d::extension::Json *json1 = cocos2d::extension::Json_getItem(jsondd, "chatValueList");
    cocos2d::extension::Json *json2 = cocos2d::extension::Json_getItemAt (json1, 0);
    cocos2d::extension::Json *json3 = cocos2d::extension::Json_getItem(json2,"message");
    cocos2d::extension::Json *json31 = cocos2d::extension::Json_getItem(json2,"chatId");


    cocos2d::extension::Json *json4= cocos2d::extension::Json_getItem(json2,"userValue");
    cocos2d::extension::Json *json5= cocos2d::extension::Json_getItem(json4,"userName");
    cocos2d::extension::Json *json6= cocos2d::extension::Json_getItem(json4,"emailId");


    val1 = json5->valuestring;
    val2 = json3->valuestring;
    val3 = json31->valueint;


    CCLOG("value:%s   %s   %d",val1.getCString(),val2.getCString(),val3);


}

}
```

Comment: Show relevant code : if this part (geting messages) is working, than it is quite useless for us. What exactlt is the problem with posting a message to the server? Do you have a problem with constructing your data to be sent? Does your server not respond?

Comment: it looks like you posted code, but can you tell us about any errors or how far you get? Does the server respond? Are you sure you are passing valid json?

Answer (score 1):

First of all, to post data using http you have to use kHttpPost not kHttpGet. So if you just set the request type to CCHttpRequest::kHttpPost you will be able to send your post data to server.

Second, if you are not having trouble with json then don't mention it in the question title. It misleads the users.